# Excel VBA checking for dots

Tags: excel, vba

Hopefully, someone can help me with this!

I have a worksheet, in this worksheet, I have first names in column C.

So I need a script/macro which gets the first letter and put it in column B with a dot. (for example, the first name is `Dave` in column C, it needs to put the letter D in column B with a dot, for example, `D.`

Also, I would like that column B get checked so there aren't any double dots.

Is this even possible?

I know I can get the first letter with `=LEFT(C1)`, but I'm trying to automate this with a script/macro.
And I found also out I can create dots in front of the letters with:

```
Sub AddDotAfter()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            cell.Value = cell.Value & "."
        Else: cell.Value = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Hope there is someone who can help me! Ty in advance!

Comment: Not clear what your question is since you say that you know how to get the first letter and also say that you know how to concatenate a dot onto the end of a string. What is preventing you from combining those two skills into a single line of code?

Comment: I would like to automate the process with a button, so when I press the button the first letter of the name appears in column B and those first letters will get a dot added to them.

Also if possible I would like to check if there aren't double dots in front of the first letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Range.Offset property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) in combination with the [Left function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function):

```
Sub AddDotAfter()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value = Left$(cell.Value, 1) & "."
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much this also works perfectly for me!!!

Comment: How can I close this question?

Comment: See the link in my comment above

Comment: Hi @PEH, If people also have second, third, and 4th name, how can I adjust the code to also get those first letters and add a dot?

Comment: @GenjutsuGhost This is another question. Please ask a new question for that make sure you give proper example input data and desired output for that data, as well as what you have tried so far to achieve that yourself.